# Group dynamics, family life and childrearing aboard a generational sailing fleet

Tags: society, psychology, age-of-sail

**Background**

A while back I posed a scenario of [a privately owned nomadic trading fleet](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/174409/is-a-privately-owned-nomadic-trading-fleet-economically-viable) that sailed around the world for centuries. A commercial enterprise spanning multiple generations, without any port or shore they call their home. See that question for more background about the world and the economy. But in brief; it's a 14th-century technology and society, and geographically it looks like the Indian ocean and the lands surrounding it.

[The answer I accepted](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/174464/51138) laid out a very good explanation and justification for the business side of things (and you can treat that as canonical, sans the Vikings), but in the first section there are some broad statements on psychology that many people had issues with.

So rather than debate that in comments and anger some moderator, let's talk psychology here. I want to tweak or expand my scenario for realism, doing respect to the dynamics of group psychology which I am not at all an expert in, without resorting to stereotypes.

**The scenario**

Some fixed stipulations:

- There's a nomadic trading fleet that carries loads from port to port without calling any their home; a diverse crew made up of many ethnicities and different skillsets, that survive amidst mighty nations and pirates through the skill and knowledge acquired over the many decades of experience. They can defend themselves but they're not pirates. Don't frame challenge this part; take your concerns about economic realism to the linked question.
- There is no shore office, no home port, no village of families that is aligned with this fleet. If all the boats sink, there's nothing left of the enterprise.
- A certain fraction of the people aboard the fleet is generational: they were born and raised there and serve until they retire. This fraction cannot be 100% because then there's too many minors aboard the ship; still, my interest is in maximising it to have the highest "generational fleet" aesthetic.
- Some people born aboard the fleet leave voluntarily or are kicked off if they do not fit in. If couples on the boat generally have six children, then four can decide to leave the boat (and live with their retired relatives), so only the most suitable 30% stays aboard; hopefully contributing to social coherence.
- Similarly, hired sailors are selected for how well they can deal with this way of living. Through selection at every stage, I hope to end up with an agreeable bunch that's fine with spending a good fraction of their lives in relatively cramped spaces. The best hired sailors join the generation faction organically (by marriage).
- I don't want strict gender separation from boat to boat. It does not feel right to me. Of course some of the jobs on the fleet are going to have inherent gender bias, but I want to minimise social separation. The whole fleet should feel like one community, not two subcultures.

And here's some of my assumptions. They can be changed to make the scenario work better, but I'll give my concerns for each.

- The fleet consists of about half a dozen ships, ranging in size from [yay big](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/caravelle-au-dessus-du-fond-blanc-64779785.jpg) to [yay big](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Lewis_R._French_NHL.jpg).

  - The ships should not be threateningly ship-of-the-line large, they should be faster and more manoeuvrable than the average warship, and if any one ship is sunk then the fleet should still have most of their wealth aboard the other vessels. On the other hand, tiny boats are no good for living, let alone raising a family.
- There's about 150-200 people in total, including children.

  - Enough to crew all the boats with some to spare, not so much that feeding them all becomes impossible on trading profits.
- They make port about once to twice a week. Smaller ships may be sent out more often.

  - This world is pretty interconnected; I think this is a valid number for how many ports there are and the distances between them.

Anything unmentioned is open for interpretation.

**Question**

Generally speaking, what can I do with my scenario, either by tweaking the numbers or adding stuff to it, to make it realistic from a psychological point of view? Specifically, I am interested in maximising the proportion of the sailors that's native to the fleet, maximising social coherence, subject to some constraints for ship design and population, and using selection of both native and hired personnel for coherence.

**Addendum**

I will divorce the available space on the ships from reality. I think designing boats that are spacious enough for childrearing is an engineering question, which is out of scope here (might use a third question for that). Let's say that space is what we would call cramped, but as filled to the brim as it was historically. For a number: every kind of ship in the KeizerHarm-universe will only require half the crew that they do on Earth. People will generally not have private cabins but there can be rooms set aside for things not essential to navigating.

Comment: I would appreciate if the close-voter explained why my question is story-based, so that I may yet fix it. I want to maximise social coherence aboard the fleet through measures or changes to the scenario, all systematic changes. I am not looking for a plot or story that makes the sailors all like each other.

Comment: Does the fleet all stay together, or are the ships usually on their own, sailing different routes?

Comment: @JohnDallman They stay together for the most part. Specific vessels may be sent out occasionally.

Comment: What *kind* of ships are those? A square rigger needs a lot more men than a schooner of the same capacity. After determining how many men are required to man the ship, guess how many of their jobs can be performed by women or children. Sailing ships are *cramped* at best, more usually overcrowded, and *dangerous*; definitely not a place to have a family life and raise children. Sailors aboard sailing ships have exactly zero expectation of privacy. (And the service life of a medieval ship was not all that long, either. They were made of wood; wood rots and it is eaten by shipworms.)

Comment: I think you'll see a lot of misunderstandings between "hired" and "native" folks due to their different backgrounds. You'll see tension and sexual politics between native folks with spouses aboard, and various horny singles. (A bad breakup will be worse when neither can leave the ship until the next port.) The politics of who-is-in-charge can become quite convoluted when mixed with long-term relationships -- maybe its the nominal Captain, maybe it's their spouse, maybe it's their uncle who used to be skipper until last year.

Comment: @AlexP You have a point, but I think that these ship designs - which do not need to correspond at all with historical designs - can be made relatively spacious, because they were designed or modified for families to live in. Low-maintenance designs can have more "empty space" per ship, that you can fill with either cargo or playing space for toddlers (which can be the same). Also, individual ships need not be centuries old; they can replace them.

Comment: @user535733 You're right, but you can at least put feuding people on different boats in the fleet. Managing who crews what ship at any time will be an important job, certainly.

Comment: (1) There is no such thing as a low-maintenance wooden sailing ship. (2) If wooden sailing ships *could* be made less cramped than they were in real life, they *would have been*. Ship designers were neither sadists nor idiots; but they had to work with the limitations of the available ship-building technology. (And, again, life aboard a medieval wooden sailing ship was *dangerous*.)

Comment: 1) I said *relatively*. 2) Ship designers weren't sadists but their motivation was profit, not comfort, and their customers did not include toddlers. And another point: [children as young as 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabin_boy) were already in service in historical sailboats. Basically I only need enough extra space to get children through their first decade without too many emotional issues.

Comment: @AlexP I give up, I do not know enough about ship design to have good opinions about space. I added an addendum to treat space aboard the ships as out of question scope, because it would be a separate question to engineer the boats to allow for separate rooms.

Comment: What's wrong with having lots of kids? Once they're four or five, put em to work! Little monkies can climb and get into all sorts of tight spaces and can be made quite useful.

Comment: @elemtilas a gaggle of friendly little kids can be quite helpful, but I doubt that having 10% of your populace be hormonal teenagers is going to be practical.

Comment: You do realise that having a workforce comprised of hormonal teenagers was the norm right into the 20th century, right? Check out *The Jungle* some time! Best way to build a believable fictional world is to understand the history of the real world.

Comment: @elemtilas The life expectancy and health of those factory workers are not something I aim to mimic. Part of a successful generational fleet is the mental health of people involved.

Comment: They're living in a generational nomadic fleet situation in the 14th century. Life expectancy sucked in the 14th century, even for the well to do. Child labour was a fact of life in the 14th century. Fair enough that you don't wish to mimic that, but do understand that your result will be unbelievable, like a whitewashed Diznee fairy tale: all sugar plums and candy and no Cinderella actually busting her ass fetching water and scrubbing everything by hand and shovelling ashes and chopping wood. As for mental health, give them Christianity (or a religion along similar...

Comment: (cont) ... lines and foundational principles) and they'll have all the grace and mental health support they need to bear up under any circumstances life aboard a generational fleet can throw at them!

Comment: @elemtilas I think you're grossly oversimplifying things (and being rather condescending). You mentioned The Jungle, which talks about the Industrial Revolution specifically, an era characterised by the exploitation of impoverished families and abusive labour conditions that was not seen before. People did not invent socialism in the renaissance; because Victorian conditions were awful by medieval standards. Christianity as a cure for mental health  conditions is not a helpful suggestion in the least.

Comment: @elemtilas I am not making a Disney tale. There will be child labour, there will be mismanagement, there will be conflict. But there will not be such abuse that the enterprise will lose its own children at an unsustainable rate.

Answer (score 4):

I find the idea really fun honestly.

**Round one: kid skull VS falling pulley or how to ensure nobody leaves**

This part is not necessarily fully tied to psychology but it is an important point for the feasibility of your society.

Being a crewman on a ship was *dangerous* even for experienced marineer: illness, poor quality food, general danger of the open sea you would have a lot of losses... But with kids? Let's be nice and say mother can nurture their child with only food being found on a ship - you still have all of the high risk of medieval child bearing, but on top of that you had the extreme condition of the sea?

The amount of children they will be able to successfully raise until they are old enough to do anything will be quite low, way lower than it already was at this period in normal conditions mind you, so I don't think you can afford to only keep 30% of them especially if you want this fleet to be composed of substantial amount. You better have a culture in there that heavily emphasises how much better it is to be a sailor than earthbound.

**Round two: intimawhat?**

14th century ship weren't known for their luxurious life condition, sailor being stacked on top of each other in the belly of the ship and the like. It's great to have a good community spirit, but not that great if you want to get intimate with somebody, let alone form a couple. So I see two main options, either the culture there is way more open with people being just one big pile of people stacked onto each other, or you will have to dedicate some part of the ship to private life. That space would be shared by a lot of people but not at the same time. Be it the mess being reserved to courtship between bachelor at certain time of the day, and more "private" room  that can be accessed and locked to actually be intimate without having to bear the sight of hundreds of crewmates.

**Round 3: community**

Quick aside but 200 people in the total of the fleet is just not enough. Caravel & big ship like you showed could accommodate between 50 and 80 crewmen. If you get 5 of them you are already way past your upper limit, without taking into account the small ships. Cause the bigger the community, the more chance you have that everybody will find something they like

I think to "spice up" the life on ship it would be a good idea to have each ship or ship size to have a specific social purpose. For example, smaller ships being the place where teens learn the rope of the craft.

**Conclusion: the dark soul of traveling merchant**
In conclusion, psychology-wise it's far from unfeasible, if you can find a way for people to get a bit of time away from the big group of people. Not having an anchor point isn't that big of a deal if you have a strong enough bound between them. Your biggest problem mainly come from just how deadly the sea is as an environment.

Comment: Sailors being stacked like sardines was *luxury*. In real life sailing ships they had to take turns sleeping, because the available berth space could not accomodate more than *maybe* one half of the crew at the same time. Even funnier when a man and his wife are assigned to different watches.

Comment: @AlexP Noted, space aboard ships is now out of the question scope.

Comment: @KeizerHarm well, with the tiny ship you showed us, it kinda is.  it's probably the biggest psycological hurdle. if you could afford a bed & room for everybody then all of this would be super easy

Comment: @shas I'll make it slightly less cramped than historically, in order for the scenario to work. Most people still sleep in hammocks, but there can be a few rooms for family time. Question then becomes how to utilise the little available space.